# PECL APC install --- ERROR: 'make' failed

Tags: centos, php, php5, alternative-php-cache, centos6.5

I get the following error when running `sudo pecl install apc`.

```
/var/tmp/APC/apc_cache.c: In function '_apc_cache_user_update':
/var/tmp/APC/apc_cache.c:818: error: 'IS_CONSTANT_INDEX' undeclared (first use in this function)
/var/tmp/APC/apc_cache.c:818: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
/var/tmp/APC/apc_cache.c:818: error: for each function it appears in.)
/var/tmp/APC/apc_cache.c:820: error: 'IS_CONSTANT_ARRAY' undeclared (first use in this function)
make: *** [apc_cache.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

I have **php 5.5.12** installed and these following libraries are all up to date:

```
sudo yum install php-pear
sudo yum install php-devel
sudo yum install httpd-devel
sudo yum install gcc
sudo yum install pcre-devel
sudo pecl install apc-beta
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

APC doesn't have support for PHP 5.5, the last version it was updated to work with was 5.4, and it hasn't seen updates since except for bug fixes in 2012.

If you did want to make it work with 5.5 you could try redefining IS_CONSTANT_ARRAY and IS_CONSTANT_INDEX to be IS_CONSTANT_AST since this has superseded them, however that's no guarantee of success if it eventually does compile.

Comment: PHP 5.5 has a built-in OPcode cache: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.opcache.php